# Given a list of values, how can I pick the value greater than the previous one?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

Here is the problem. There is a bot that plays rock, paper, scissor. The bot should pick the move that would have beaten its previous one. ex: Round 1: Bot picks paper, so round 2 the bot should pick scissors. and so on...

The code I have so far is this: Method that makes the first move a random move.

```
let randomizer = GKARC4RandomSource()
// TODO: - REFACTOR
func botRandomChoice() -> Symbol {
    let botSymbol = randomizer.nextInt(upperBound: 3) // or 2
    if botSymbol == 0 {
        print("RandomSymbol is rock")
        return .rock
    } else if botSymbol == 1 {
        print("Random Symbol is paper")
        return .paper
    } else {
        print("Random Symbol is scissor")
        return .scissor
    }
}
```

Model:

```
struct Game {
    var symbol: Symbol
    var state: GameState
}

enum Symbol: String {
    case rock = ""
    case paper = ""
    case scissor = "✂️"

    func outcome(botChoice: Symbol) -> GameState {
        if self == botChoice {
            return .draw
        }
        switch self {
        case .rock:
            return botChoice == .scissor ? .win : .lose
        case .paper:
            return botChoice == .rock ? .win : .lose
        case .scissor:
            return botChoice == .paper ? .win : .lose
        }
    }
}
```

What have I tried so far?
I am trying to think of the best way to do this. I am considering an if or a switch statement that would look like this:

```
var moveNumber = 1
var symbol: Symbol
if moveNumber == 1 {
// It is the first move so pick a random choice.
let boySymbol = randomizer.nextInt(upperBound: 3)
}
if moveNumber == 2 {
// Look at previous move
let previous = botSymbol
// Use the move that would beat it.
if previous == .rock {
// play paper
```

I think there is a better way to solve or code this but I am lost. I was even considering a linked list? maybe a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by adding a method to the enum that defines the rules and that can be used to select the "greater" value. This method return the symbol that beats `self`

```
func beatenBy() -> Symbol {
    switch self {
    case .rock:
        return .paper
    case .paper:
        return .scissor
    case .scissor:
        return .rock
    }
}
```

Now we can also use this to simplify the `outcome` method to

```
func outcome(other: Symbol) -> GameState {
    if self == other {
        return .draw
    }
    return self.beatenBy() == other ? .lose : .win
}
```

I am not exactly sure how you want to play the game (in code) so here is a simple example of a first round and preparation for the second round using `beatenBy`

```
var myChoice: Symbol!
var botChoice = botRandomChoice()

myChoice = .paper

let result = myChoice.outcome(other: botChoice)

//set next bot choice based on winning choice
botChoice = result == .win ? myChoice.beatenBy() : botChoice.beatenBy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have already started to create a Game struct I'd use this to contain all the components as well as track state.  I'd also introduce an `Outcome` enum to allow you to return a `.win` or a `.lose`.  Moving all the comparison logic for `Symbol` into the enum tidies up the code: use the `nextMove` method to return the next move, and the `play(against:)' method to 'play' a turn.

```
struct Game {
   enum Outcome {
      case win
      case lose
   }

   enum Symbol: String, CaseIterable {
      case rock = ""
      case paper = ""
      case scissor = "✂️"

      func play(against other: Symbol) -> Outcome {
         switch self {
         case .paper: return other == .scissor ? .lose : .win
         case .rock: return other == .paper ? .lose : .win
         case .scissor: return other == .rock ? .lose : .win
         }
      }

      func nextMove() -> Symbol {
         switch self {
         case .paper: return .scissor
         case .rock: return .paper
         case .scissor: return .rock
         }
      }
   }

   var moves: Int = 0
   var move : Symbol = Symbol.allCases[Int.random(in: 0...2)] //random starting symbol

   mutating func playARound(with other: Symbol) -> Outcome {
      move = move.nextMove()
      moves += 1
      return move.play(against: other)
   }
}
```

Then you can instantiate a game and use its `.playARound(with:)` method for each round you want to play

```
var game = Game()
let result = game.playARound(with: .rock)
```

Comment: :@Joakim Danielson put in a very similar solution, and got it in first, so give him the kudos :-)

Comment: and he has accounted for the draw, which I forgot all about!